# How to fix iframe element with changing src

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to write a small bit of code that will access pages of my geometry textbook. Originally I had the code redirect you, but it was to hard to navigate because of all of the going back you had to do. Instead I decided to use an `<iframe>` element in order to make it easier to change from page to page. For some reason whenever i press the submit button, the page reloads and doesn't do anything to the iframe element. I'm wondering what to do to fix this.

```
<head>
<style>
body {
Background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightgreen, 
dodgerblue);
}

</style>

<body>
<style>
.button {
background-color: lightblue;
border: 2px solid lightblue;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 3em;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 2px solid lightblue;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: hsla(210, 100.0, 55.9, 0.0);
}

.inputstuff {
width: 40%;
margin: auto;
}

</style>
<div class="inputstuff">

<form>
<input type="text" id="pg" placeholder="page no.(with zeros)" />

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

<iframe id="pdf" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var gaybo = document.getElementById("pg").value;
var n = gaybo.length
if (n == 1) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
if (n == 2) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
if (n == 3) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
}

</script>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work just add these few changes

```
<button onclick="myFunction(event)"> Submit</button>
```

and in the function pass the event and call preventDefault to prevent reloading of the page

```
    function myFunction(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a type to your button.

Try putting type="button" on your button like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `type="button"` to your `button`, otherwise your button will get the default type that depends on the browser and could be `type="submit"` which will reload your page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Submit</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes

**type**

The type of the button. Possible values are:

- `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
- `reset`: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
- `button`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
Background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightgreen, 
dodgerblue);
}

</style>

<body>
<style>
.button {
background-color: lightblue;
border: 2px solid lightblue;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 3em;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 2px solid lightblue;
border-radius: 5px;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: hsla(210, 100.0, 55.9, 0.0);
}

.inputstuff {
width: 40%;
margin: auto;
}

</style>
<div class="inputstuff">

<form>
<input type="text" id="pg" placeholder="page no.(with zeros)" />

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

<iframe id="pdf" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var gaybo = document.getElementById("pg").value;
var n = gaybo.length
if (n == 1) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
if (n == 2) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
if (n == 3) {
document.getElementById("pdf").src = 
"https://my.hrw.com/math11/math06_07/student/pdf/english/geo/geo_11_0" + 
gaybo + ".pdf";
}
}

</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran a quick test, if you include the type attribute in the button it appears to fix the problem:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Submit</button>
```

adding that fills my pdf box with an error message denying me access (makes sense as i dont have access to that pdf) but it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is
set the button type to button.
Without setting it, button takes it as submit.

```
<Button type="button">submit</>
```